# 2.63a texture bump in nodes

Tags: materials, node-editor

I can only use versión 2.63a due to system limitations. I'm following a tutorial and noticed that in 2.66 there's an option for texture bump in the nodes section. How can I manage a bump in nodes in version 2.63a that mimics or equals that of 2.66?

thanks in advance!
Cam

Comment: Can you link to the tutorial in question? Are you in Cycles or BI?

Comment: What limits you to using 2.63?

Comment: Depending on what is limiting you to 2.63, you are probably better off trying to get around that, rather than attempting to simulate new features.

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of blender (added in 2.65) allow you to feed normal data (bump maps) into the shader nodes allowing the shader to adjust itself to the altered surface of the model. Also the normal Map node was added that gives us more control over how the normal map is applied.

The closest alternative you have in 2.63 is to connect your bump map into the displace socket of the Material Output.